# Android Room Not working with private properties

Tags: android, android-room

I currently have a `Note` class.

I have setup all room annotations and it seems to find the getters of my private properties.

Here is my class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
public final class Note {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    @NonNull
    private final String mId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "title")
    @Nullable
    private final String mTitle;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "desc")
    @Nullable
    private final String mDesc;

    @Ignore
    public Note(@Nullable String title, @Nullable String desc) {
        this(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), title, desc);
    }


    public Note(@NonNull String id, @Nullable String title, @Nullable String desc) {
        mId = id;
        mTitle = title;
        mDesc = desc;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getmId() {
        return mId;
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getmTitle() {
        return mTitle;
    }

    @Nullable
    public String getmDesc() {
        return mDesc;
    }

}
```

Everything is there, however when I build my project. I get this in the `Messages Gradle Build`:

```
Error:(18, 26) error: Cannot find getter for field.
Error:(22, 26) error: Cannot find getter for field.
Error:(26, 26) error: Cannot find getter for field.
```

which links back to :

```
private final String mId;
private final String mTitle;
private final String mDesc;
```

But I do have the getters, and they are public.

I am currently using:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.0-alpha3"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha3"
```

For `Room`

Any ideas?

Comment: Try removing the `m` from the getters (e.g., `getDesc()` instead of `getmDesc()`) and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Wow. It was that simple, haha thanks! if you want to make it an answer I will mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Room is looking for getter method for eg mId property which by convention is getMId not getmId.

I suggest renaming fields to id, title, desc and mehtods to getId() getTitle() and getDesc() to improve readability.